# Yii escaping quotes in UpdateAll where clause

Tags: php, yii

Is there a 'Yii' way of escaping quotes when updating or selecting by a textfield?

```
MyModel::model()->updateAll( array( 'status_id' => 1 ), 'name="' . $model->name . '"' );
```

If `$model-name` contains double quotes in this case it obviously breaks the statement. Is there a 'Yii' way of escaping this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly that would be:

```
MyModel::model()->updateAll(array('status_id' => 1), 'name=:name', array(':name' => $model->name));
```